# show search icon in nav menu, when clicked/toggle show search field - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, menu, navigation

I'm trying to add a search icon to my navbar on wordpress using wpresidence theme on Wordpress,

Once clicked, i would like the search bar to appear, i wouldn't mind if it makes use of the current advanced search feature.

Would be very grateful for your help

```
function add_last_nav_item($items, $args) {
  if ($args->menu == 'header_menu') {
        $homelink = get_search_form();
        $items = $items;
        $items .= '<li>'.$homelink.'</li>';
        return $items;
  }
  return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_last_nav_item', 10, 2 );
```

--- i've tried using bobsearch plugin and it didn't work and also entered this into my functions.php code but it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Your hook looks fine. But the condition maybe wrong. If you want to check theme location when register with them, try this:

```
if($args->theme_location == "header_menu")
```

$args objects is an object containing wp_nav_menu() arguments.

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Here is searchform.php

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
    <label>
        <input class="search-field" placeholder="Search" value="" name="s" type="search">
    </label>
    <input class="search-submit" value="Search" type="submit">
</form>
```

> Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/zdcmmfe9/1/

Comment: hi there, the menu bar appears when i use the above code, but i would like a search icon to be shown and on click show the search field

Comment: For that part you need to play a bit with javascript. The approach is in searchform.php file you create an input and a button. Set display of the input to none and add a handler to click event of the button to change display of input. I would like to give you a demo later.